# Verifying a backup can be restored before restoring and introduce error handling

Tags: sql-server, database-administration

Just wondering what is the best possible way to introduce error handling in my code. I just want to ensure the backup file given to us by a third party can be restored before the restore process can be undertake.

```
RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM disk =  '\\ServerName\Database_backup.bak'
```

I want to only restore if the backup isn't corrupt, if it is corrupt then do nothing otherwise proceed with the backup. What would be the best way to introduce error handling please.

Comment: Have you tried RESTORE HEADERONLY and RESTORE VERIFYONLY?

Comment: Yes I am aware of these commands however I would like to automate this script to run daily. I just want to run the restore only if the database is a workable with that command but need help with error handling side to run only when the backup is restorable if you get what I mean

Comment: I used TRY/CATCH with backup, not sure it will catch any exceptions in RESTORE. If not, I think you can wrap your restore in an SP, and TRY/CATCH the call to the SP